# How to use a movieclip as a boundary for another dragable object in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

How to use a movieclip as a boundary for another dragable object?

All I know is, we can use a rectangle for boundary in start drag .

```
dragable_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag);
function start_drag(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
    dragable_mc.startDrag(false, rect);
}
```

What is the way to drag a movieclip in another movieclip in flash by as3?
(like as I shown in pic)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a dynamic shape, you'd have to log the x,y coordinates of the drag-able object every frame upon drag. Then do a bitmap-hitpoint test with the boundary to check if the object is out of bounds. If it is outside, return to the last coordinates that isn't out of bound.

**edit**:

The two variables you need to rename are dragTarget and bound_mc

dragTarget is your dragable_mc

bound_mc is the name of the movieclip of your boundary.

bound_mc need to be in png format, and the out of bounds area MUST be transparent. example: [image: Example]

```
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

stop();

var bmd:BitmapData =new BitmapData(600, 400, true, 0x000000);
var rect:Rectangle;
var lastPt:Point = new Point();

function init():void {
    rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
    setUpBitmap();
}

function setUpBitmap():void {
    bmd.draw(bound_mc);

    dragTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag);
}

function start_drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    dragTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag);

    lastPt.x = dragTarget.x;
    lastPt.y = dragTarget.y;

    dragTarget.startDrag(false, rect);
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, logPoint);
}

function stop_drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, logPoint);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag);
    dragTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag);

    dragTarget.stopDrag();
}

function logPoint(event:Event):void {
    var curPoint:Point = new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);

    if ( bmd.hitTest(new Point( bound_mc.x, bound_mc.y ), 0, curPoint) ) {
        lastPt = curPoint;
    } else {
        dragTarget.x = lastPt.x;
        dragTarget.y = lastPt.y;

        stage.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
    }
}

init();
```

Comment: I try your idea, and I should say its not work, hitTestObject use a rectangle around my boundary to check  hit .

Comment: bitmapdata.hittest, not hittestobject. Ill see if i write up an example later.
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest()

Comment: oh sorry, let me try again ;)

Comment: @XFa I updated my post with the codes. tried and tested

Comment: @user1234567 , thanks ... it worked very fine :) . important point is that we should set registration point of bound_mc to top left corner.

Comment: @VC.One yes, very well.