# Detect when one object is over another? (HTML5)

Tags: html, actionscript-3, html5-canvas, game-development

I’m creating a game in HTML5 Canvas that requires an action to execute once one object (a graphic) goes over another object (also a graphic).

I’ve tried methods I’ve seen online, but they don’t seem to work.
I was expecting the code to be similar to the Mouseover function, but I’ve tried with this and it did not work.

Is this a possible function? Can it be achieved with graphics?

This was my original code in AS3:

```
        object1.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision)

        function handleCollision( e:Event ):void
        {
            if (object2.hitTestPoint(object1.x, object1.y, true))
            {
               // object2 collided with object1
                trace("Collision");u

            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I translate this code from AS3 to HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567421/how-do-i-translate-this-code-from-as3-to-html5)

Comment: For future reference, please [edit] your question instead of reposting it with slight tweaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have found that collision detection between graphics is not possible in HTML5 for some reason. I have instead used an alternate method where if object2’s co-ordinates are the same as object1’s and the Y-axis is not above it, then the reaction will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [BitmapData.hitTest](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest()) for pixel level detection. This is an argument, so you'd need to have a function like enter_frame to constantly check for overlaps.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530091/how-to-use-a-movieclip-as-a-boundary-for-another-dragable-object-in-as3/55530145#55530145) you can find an example of using BitmapData.hitTest to detect losing contact with a sprite that represents a play area. Your requirement is opposite, to detect contact with another sprite. But it is essentially the same idea.

Hope it helps